# Get entity by ID from multiple entities in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Suppose we have a set of entities:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->findBy(array('cat' => 1));
```

What is the best way to pick up a single entity out of this set by ID? Of course I can search for it with a loop or with `array_filter`, e.g.:

```
$entity = null;
foreach ($entities as $_entity) {
    if ($_entity->getId() == $id) {
        $entity = $_entity;
        break;
    }
}
```

But maybe there is a build in Symfony/Doctrine method for that?

Comment: @Pazi Nope, that will run a new SQL query. I need to get a single entity out of entities received previously.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the filter method from the [ArrayCollection](http://api.nellafw.org/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_filter) class, but it's not so different from looping entities like you're doing

```
$idToSearch = $n;

$newCollection = $entities->filter(
    function($entity) use ($idToSearch) {
        return $entity->getId() == $idToSearch;
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `findBy` returns `ArrayCollection`. It seems to be a simple array.

Comment: you can instantiate a new ArrayCollection from an array: $collection = new Collections\ArrayCollection($entities);

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through them with `foreach`, although that scales very poorly. Depending on the amount of results you expect, it could be faster to simply run two queries.